# AWS EventBridge scheduled events with custom details?

Tags: aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to build an architecture where a single Lambda is triggered on a schedule with multiple parameter sets.
So for example if I have three sets of parameters and set schedule to ten minutes I expect to get three executions every ten minutes.

Is there a way to trigger an EventBridge scheduled events with custom properties so I can pass parameters to Lambda? I've noticed the *details* property in the [event schema](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/event-types.html#schedule-event-type) but couldn't find any reference to its usage with scheduled events.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- To trigger a single lambda function for multiple parameter sets, you can create a separated schedule rule for each parameter set.
- To provide input to your triggered lambda function you can set "configure input" when you select your lambda function as a target, for example you can provide your input in json format.

Comment: if you provide your input in JSON format, your input will be static, right? That means you will only provide the same input every time you call the function. But what if you want to send a different value based on the triggered event?

Comment: When I set an Input, it replaces the whole event. What if I want to add input without loosing the default properties that come when Input is not set?